# Extract all columns of nested tibble data based on condition

Tags: r, nested, purrr, tibble

For example I want to extract and add all variables based on minimal value of one variable (i.e. year in nested gapminder by country)

```
library(tidyverse)
data("gapminder")

gap_nested <- gapminder %>%
  nest(data = -country) %>%
  mutate(year = map(data, ~ min(.x$year)))
```

How do I do this? )

Comment: Can you show expected output for first few lines?

Comment: @RonakShah, I expect to get the same like `gapminder %>% filter(year == min(year))`. In case of Gapminder dataset it's ok, because every country has the same min year. When min "year" varies this doesn't work

Comment: Do you mean minimum year of each `country` ? So `gapminder %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  filter(year == min(year))` ?

Answer (score 0):

### You can use the filter function

You can use the filter function from they `dplyr` package (included in `tidyverse`), like in this example:

```
gap_nested <- gapminder %>%
  nest(data = -country) %>%
  mutate(year = map(data, ~ min(.x$year))) %>%
  filter(year == 1960)
```

This will return only countries which have minimum year equals to 1960.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works only if I know what the min year exactly is in each nested data. When it varies  - doesn't

Comment: @SashaPoda Just change `year == 1960` with `year == min(year)`